# Cassandra 'bad state', cannot run compaction?

Tags: cassandra

We are using 72% of hard-drive, deleted about half of rows ( using cqlsh ), however Cassandra(3.9.0) cannot complete compaction, throws **java.lang.RuntimeException: Not enough space for compaction, estimated sstables = 1, expected write size = 799429448428**

Compaction triggers very 24 hrs and fails.

Note that is a single node setup and 'gc_grace_seconds=0';

Is there any other way to force removal of deleted data?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add to your post the output of `describe table <keyspace>.<table>` so the compaction strategy and any other settings may be seen? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can try splitting large table (with **sstablesplit**) into smaller ones, so the compaction will require less space (this is requires to stop the node).

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableSplit.html